# How to fill the entire cell with a color in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, plugins, colors, ckeditor, cell

I created a plugin that allows me to put a background color in a table cell in 1 click.
The problem is that I do not know how to make the whole cell colored.

Here is the code of my plugin.

```js
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'TrameF', { //meme nom que le dossier associé
    init: function( editor ) {

        editor.addCommand( 'TrameF', {
            exec: function( editor ) {
                
                editor.insertHtml( '<p style=" background-color : #BCE0EA;">'+
                    ' </p> ');
            }
         });
    }
});
```

[image: and this is my result :]

Can someone help me ? Thanks, have a good day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the `<td>` element and set its style. To do that, you need to traverse backwards the DOM from the point you clicked:

```
var el = editor.getSelection().getStartElement();
while (el) {
    if (el.getName() == 'td' || el.getName() == 'th') {
        el.setStyle('background-color', '#BCE0EA');
        break;
    }
    el = el.getParent();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. :)